# What should i set in for_each operator in child module to use for_each in root module?

Tags: terraform

What should i set in for_each operator in child & root module to use for_each in root module? I need multiple instances of the same module, i ll have many alert rules for prometheus from alert module.

Root module:

```
module "alert-rules" {
  source = "./module/alert-rules"

  prometheus_id = var.prometheus_id
  for_each = { 
    data = {   #HOW TO SET data ARGUMENT CORRECTLY?
      "alert1" = {name="...", period=..., etc } 
      "alert2" = {name="...", period=..., etc} 
    }
  }
}
```

Child module:

```
resource "aws_prometheus_rule_group_namespace" "alert-rules" {
  name         = each.key
  workspace_id = var.prometheus_id
  for_each     = WHAT TO SET HERE ???
  data         = <<EOF
groups:
  - name: ${each.key}
    rules:
    - alert: ${each.value.alert}
      expr: ${each.value.expr}
      for: ${each.value.period}
      labels:
        severity: ${each.value.severity}
      annotations:
        summary: ${each.value.summary}
EOF
}
```

Comment: None, that's the point of locals - they are local.

Comment: I found a possible way how it d work without locals, for example: if in root module i specify: 'for_each = { "alert1" = {name="...", period=... } "alert2" = {name="...", period=...} }'. But what should i specify in child module: 'for_each  = WHAT TO SET HERE ???'

Comment: It depends, do you need multiple instances of the same module or multiple instances of the resource?

Comment: I need multiple instances of the same module, i ll have many alert rules for prometheus from alert module

Comment: Can you update the question then with the changes you've made?

Comment: You would have to define appropriate variables at the module level and pass them the values from the `each` object when calling the module.

Comment: I defined vars at the module level & passed values to it in root module, but argument 'data' contains all vars & is located inside for_each operator, how to pass 'data' correctly? i receive error: "data" is required, but no definition was found

Comment: Instead of `each.key` and `each.value` you would assign a variable, e.g., `expr: var.expression`.

Comment: If I use var instead of each.value, i need to use type=set in var, but it'd be not convenient to use many values in variable, i can have hundreds values for variable (set)

Comment: Well, I can't see a different way. Unless you want one instance of the module with multiple instances of the resource.

Answer (score -1):

You have to define a variable `alert-rules` in the child module.
Afterwards, I don't really see the point of putting a variable in local without modification

```
variable "prometheus_id" {
  type = string
}

locals {
  alert-rules = var.alert-rules
}
```

Comment: it isnt convenient to use vars, because alert-rules will contain many fields (name, expression, period, severity, summary, etc). There can be hundreds rules. With locals it d be more convenient to work